# Select from dynamic table in function without using EXECUTE

Tags: function, postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Can we select inside a PostgreSQL function without using `EXECUTE`? 
I'm trying to use `quote_ident()` to create dynamic SQL but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_server(p_id text)
RETURNS integer AS $$ 
DECLARE 
   serialnum_value INTEGER; 
   STATEMENT TEXT;
BEGIN
  STATEMENT := 'tbl' || substr($1, 1, 4);  
  SELECT serialnum INTO serialnum_value FROM quote_ident(STATEMENT ) WHERE id = $1;
  RETURN serialnum;
END;
```

Does anybody have idea how to select from dynamic table in a PostgreSQL function without using `EXECUTE`?

Comment: 1) It can not be done without `EXECUTE`. 2) Why you do not want to use `EXECUTE`?

Comment: EXECUTE takes more time, right? 
My old function using STATIC table, runtime : 30 ms
My new function using EXECUTE DYNAMIC table, runtime : 90 ms

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid execute here, per igor's comment. The best alternative is to create a function that creates a function, which you can then call as needed. Example:

```
create function gen_select_server(p_id text)
  returns boolean
as $gen$
begin
  execute $exec$
  create function $exec$ || quote_ident('select_server_' || p_id) || $exec$
    returns integer
  as $body$
  begin
    return serialnum
    from $exec$ || quote_ident('tbl_' || p_id) || $exec$
    where id = $exec$ || quote_literal('id_' || p_id) || $exec$;
  end;
  $body$ language plpgsql;
  $exec$;
  return true;
end;
$gen$ language plpgsql;

-- usage:
select gen_select_server('1234');   -- call this only once; uses execute
select * from select_server_1234(); -- no execute here
```

As the above highlights, it can get messy with string delimiters. Also note that the above isn't your original function -- it's primarily to illustrate how to quote things properly within the big `$exec$` "string" block.

I'd recommend to stick to using execute, that being said. Or using an ORM, for that matter. Maintaining these micro-optimizations is potentially a pain worse than the superficial gain in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute dynamic SQL without [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in [**PL/pgSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html). That's what *makes* it dynamic in the first place.

But you can streamline your function quite a bit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_server(p_id text, OUT serial_value integer) AS
$func$ 
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT serialnum FROM tbl' || left($1::text, 4)) || ' WHERE id = $1'
   USING $1
   INTO  serial_value;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

- [Normally you would have to sanitize any identifier.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
  But you **do not need** `quote_ident()` in this special case, since the only dynamic component are 4 digits from an `integer`. Neither SQL injection nor illegal identifiers are possible this way.
- Pass the *value* of `p_id` as value using the `USING` clause.
- Reduce the number of assignments. Those are comparatively expensive in plpgsql. You only need a single SQL statement to do everything.
- The `OUT` parameter helps to shorten the syntax.
- I also made the function `STRICT` (`RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`), since it would not make sense with `NULL` as input.
- `left()` is slightly faster than `substr()`.